# istio egressgateway: routing through a static IP

Tags: routes, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I am trying to route outbound traffic from an application in my GKE cluster through a static IP, as the destination server requires whitelisting IP for access. I have been able to do this using the terraformed nat gateway, but this impacts all traffic from the cluster.

Following the istio guide on the site, I've been able to route traffic through an egressgateway pod (I can see it in the gateway logs), but I need the gateway to have a static ip, and there is no override in the helm values for egressgateway static ip.

How can I assign a static ip to the egressgateway without having to patch anything or hack it after installing istio?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing on google cloud, it seems that you can add a LoadBalancerIp to a egress istio service, fixing the ip.

Comment: By the way could you share the link you used to setup your egress gateway? Did you used the beta istio integration of google?

Comment: @AntoineDussarps adding an IP to a loadbalancer does not route traffic through it, unless you add route rules.

Also, I used the istio documentation to set up the egressgateway. Since this issue was never really solved, I just used a nat gateway and had to take the hit that everything would go through that IP.

Comment: Oh, ok, we are currently trying to do the same via the cloud NAT service, it seems to work fine for external services, but for intra GCP, our IPs get really mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

I think of your problem as having three steps. First, to fix the outgoing traffic to a particular pod.  The istio egress gateway does this for you.  Second and third, to fix the pod to a particular IP address.

If you use GCP's version of floating IP addresses, then you can assign a known IP to one of the hosts in your cluster. Then, use node affinity on the egress-gateway to schedule it to the particular host, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/

I've edited the egress deployment in one of my test clusters, to 

          `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: beta.kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - amd64
                - ppc64le
                - s390x
              - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
                operator: In
                values:
                - worker-2720002`

to pin it by the hostname label, but you'll probably want to choose and apply a new label to the node when you assign it a floating ip.  In my test, the pod is moved to the specified node, and my outgoing egress traffic does too.

Comment: While that could feasible work,The only problem with that is if the host dies or if the cluster is autoscaled down such that the host is deleted, then the egress gateway won't get scheduled and the app won't get scheduled. this would also impact any other egress gateways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also currently facing your problem. I have asked about it via GCP Support, they said currently there is no mechanism to attach certain IP to the `Egress Gateway`.

So the other solution would be to patch the istio itself. The idea is to make the `Istio Egress Gateway` pods (see related deployment via `kubectl get deployment istio-egressgateway -n istio-system`) to be deployed on certain nodes, be it:

- a dedicated vm with a static ip (you have to extend the mesh by including this vm, which I don't really know how right now)
- a different GKE Cluster just for istio-egressgateway pods, then connect it to the NAT Gateway and only apply the compute route rule on that gke cluster to nat instance. You have to enable istio on multicluster (see: https://istio.io/docs/examples/multicluster/gke/)

Note: you can always make a different Istio Egress Gateway other than the default one, just for your purpose.

Comment: GCP have NAT-as-a-gateway in an upcoming alpha but that might not fix this problem if it's like the NAT Gateway I've been using via terraform

Comment: Update: there is already cloudnat support in gke https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview

Answer (score -2):

This problem can be solved (with considerable effort) by using the new Google NAT as a service tool. However it is a Google-specific service.