# Why requests outgoing from the nodes IPs instead of the Load Balancer?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I have a K8S cluster with 3 nodes and 1 Load Balancer. I need to white label my IP in third party APIs. But instead of providing the Load Balancer's IP, I see that requests are coming from the IP of the actual node. If I scale I need to keep track of this manually? How does it working?

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to NATting your cluster's outbound traffic.

Traffic outbound of the cluster will always leave from the nodes, and not the load balancers. Load Balancers are for inbound traffic.

If you want to white label (I assume you mean "whitelist" or "allowlist"), you need to use something like Cloud NAT https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview or Cloud Router https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/router/concepts/overview to force your traffic through a known external IP which you can then allow at the third party end.

Even if you scale up to multiple nodes, if you have configured Cloud NAT/Cloud Router, you will still come out of the same external IP.

Comment: Is it available for Google Cloud Kubernetes only? or that I can apply this on other cloud providers as well?

Comment: It can be used for anything within GCP -- so GKE or GCP-based K8s. But even on other providers there should be something similar. AWS has NAT Gateways and NAT Instances, for example.

Comment: So if I use DigitalOcean for exmaple, it has to be provided by them?

Comment: Digital Ocean should provide something similar, yes. I've not used DO so be sure, but this might be of use: https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/vpc/resources/droplet-as-gateway/

Comment: Nice. But it seems that I have to create a different Droplet manually.. Is there any K8S object that can be applied, just like Ingress but for outbound requests?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a resource. The closest I am aware of is Istio's egressgateway https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/, but I could not get it to hold a static IP (my original question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740450/istio-egressgateway-routing-through-a-static-ip), which is why it's probably better to allow traffic to leave the cluster as nodes, then route the traffic using the cloud provider's own tools